# Reading url using bs4 from yahoo finance

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I am trying the following code to read the historical CSV data from yahoo finance:

```
import datetime
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


per1 = str(int(time.mktime((datetime.datetime.today() - td(days=365)).timetuple())))
per2 = str(int(time.mktime((datetime.datetime.today()).timetuple())))
url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/MSFT?period1=' + per1 + '&period2=' + per2 + '&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=OQg/YFV3fvh'
```

The `url` variable can be seen when you go to yahoo finance, type a ticker and hover over the "download data" button.

I get authentication error which I believe is due to missing cookie so I tried the following:

```
import requests
ses = requests.Session()
url1 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history?p=MSFT'
ses.get(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ses.get(url).content)
print soup.prettify()
```

I get incorrect cookie error this time.

Can someone suggest how to work around this?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Please notice that there is a [pandas library for this purpose](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io). It works really well.

Comment: I had run into threads which were showing error extracting yahoo finance data but seems it has been since fixed. Thanks. The accepted answer is a great learning tool also I must say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `crumb` parameter of the query string keeps changing, perhaps with each browser session. So, when you copy its value from the browser, close it and then use it in another instance of the browser, it expires by then.

So, it should come as no surprise that by the time you use it in your `requests` session, it doesn't recognize the cookie value and generates an error.

**Step 1**

Studying the network tab in any browser will help. In this particular case, this `crumb` part is generated probably when you click on a ticker in the main page. So you'll have to fetch that URL first.

```
tickers = ('000001.SS', 'NKE', 'MA', 'SBUX')
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}?p={0}'.format(tickers[0])
r = s.get(url, headers = req_headers)
```

This URL needs to be fetched only once. So it doesn't matter which ticker you use for this.

**Step 2**

The response returned by the server contains the value passed to the `crumb` parameter in the query string when you download the CSV file.

However, it's contained in the `script` tag of the page returned by the previous request. This means you can't use BeautifulSoup alone to extract the `crumb` value.

I initially tried `re` to extract that out of the `script` tag's text. But for some reason, I wasn't able to. So I moved to `json` for parsing it.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
script_tag = soup.find(text=re.compile('crumb'))

response_dict = json.loads(script_tag[script_tag.find('{"context":'):script_tag.find('}}}};') + 4])
crumb = response_dict['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['CrumbStore']['crumb']
```

Note that BeautifulSoup is required to extract the `script` element's contents to be later passed to `json` to parse it into a Python `dict` object.

I had to use `pprint` to print the resulting `dict` to a file to see exactly where the crumb value was stored.

**Step 3**

The final URL that fetches the CSV file looks like this:

```
for ticker in tickers:
    csv_url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{0}?period1=1506656676&period2=1509248676&interval=1d&events=history&crumb={1}'.format(ticker, crumb)

    r = s.get(csv_url, headers = req_headers)
```

**Result**

Here's the first few lines of one the files downloaded:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2017-09-29,3340.311035,3357.014893,3340.311035,3348.943115,3348.943115,144900
2017-10-09,3403.246094,3410.169922,3366.965088,3374.377930,3374.377930,191700
2017-10-10,3373.344971,3384.025879,3358.794922,3382.988037,3382.988037,179400
```

**Note:**

I used appropriate headers in both the requests. So if you skip that part and don't get the desired results, you may have to include them as well.

```
req_headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Comment: "Studying the network tab in any browser will help": Under network tab which particular variable do you look for?